# How to get local subdomains using express.js 's req.subdomains?

Tags: node.js, express

```
Here is my /etc/hosts file

##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   test.localhost
127.0.0.1   demo.localhost
127.0.0.1   test2.localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

All I need is to be able to parse out the subdomain from the url as I would have to store it in the session cookie for session use (for now). I'm not trying to do anything fancy - like set up apis or anything as of now.

Express's documentation shows that there is a req.subdomains property that lists the subdomains as an array, but with all of my local subdomains, this array shows up empty. [ i.e. when i go to demo.localhost:3000, the web app is served for sure, but on the first get function, I call req.subdomains and there is an empty array [].

How can I get these subdomain strings from my localhost:3000?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is because your host is missing a TLD.  [From the Express code](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/request.js#L327) -- subdomain offset will default to 2 because it expects something like `.com` rather than for the host to end with `localhost`.

You could use `this.app.set('subdomain offset', 1);` as part of the configuration for running locally.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very quick and very specific response. I put in this line and now I can definitely test on my local machine. Of course, I would have to remove this line for production, but that's a small price to pay for what I need to do.

Comment: You can work around it without changing code by inserting an extra subdomain, like: demo.foo.localhost